# Mysql delete a statement from one table, but related to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I need to delete all public messages older than a year where Users (message owners, senders) must be from Australia and 21 years old.

I get an error:

> ***#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join User inner join City inner join Country where Message.messa' at line 2***.

My texts do not cover even a half of the task, so if anyone could help me here.

Here is my code:

```
delete 
from Message
     inner join User 
     inner join City 
     inner join Country
where Message.message_type=0 and 
      datediff(curdate(),Message.posted) >366 and 
      User.user_id=Message.owner_id and 
      datediff(User.date_of_birth, 
               str_to_date('1/01/1991', '%m/%d/%Y')) < 366 and            
      City.city_id=User.city_id  and 
      Country.country_id=City.country_id and 
      Country.name='Australia'
```

Comment: you need to specify the common column names for inner join , ex
city inner join country on city.road = country.road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `User`  is a reserved keyword in MySQL so you need to back lit it with quotes `User` :

```
DELETE Message
FROM Message
     INNER JOIN `User`
        ON `User`.user_id = Message.owner_id
     INNER JOIN City
        ON City.city_id = `User`.city_id
     INNER JOIN Country
        ON Country.country_id = City.country_id
WHERE Message.message_type = 0 AND
      DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Message.posted) > 366 AND
      ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `User`.date_of_birth)/365) < 21 AND
      Country.name = 'Australia';
```

alternatively if you are putting joining condition in `WHERE` clause then no need to use `INNER JOIN`  :

```
delete Message
from Message, `User`, City, Country
where `User`.user_id=Message.owner_id and
      City.city_id=`User`.city_id and
      Message.message_type=0 and
      Country.country_id=City.country_id and
      datediff(curdate(),Message.posted) >366 and
      datediff(`User`.date_of_birth,
      str_to_date('1/01/1991', '%m/%d/%Y')) < 366 and
      Country.name='Australia';
```

Comment: Have tried this... Same error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join User ON User.user_id=Message.owner_id inner join City ' at line 3

Comment: `User` is a reserved word in mysql. try updated query. It should work.

Comment: OK ! Thanks ! no error now ! But 0 rows deleted... Do my datediff statements look ok to you ? Messages must be older that a year and user must be under 21.

Comment: why you hardcoded date value to '1/01/1991'? it should be  `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `User`.date_of_birth) < 21`

Comment: Still 0 rows deleted :(... Everything looks fine....

Comment: probably you need to debug a delete query by converting into select query and see the output records which will get deleted. Also make sure that `Message.posted` & `User`.date_of_birth are having column data type a `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: the problem is in both datediff statements. Message.posted & User.date_of_birth are of the datetime type. Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you tried select query?  can you post sample tables data?

Comment: Yes, now the only problem is DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), User.date_of_birth) < 21. The selection output 3 messages which are public and older than a year and the users are from Australia. However they are all under 21... So with DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), User.date_of_birth) < 21 there is no output at all (0 rows)

Comment: Same 0 rows. I have put different numbers, but no changes.

Comment: got the problem now. to calculate age it should be `ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `User`.date_of_birth)/365) < 21`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

When you do inner join with two tables, you have to give a condition to join both the tables in the on condition..

```
delete M
 from  Message M inner join User U
    on U.user_id=M.owner_id 
 inner join City C
    on City.city_id=U.city_id 
 inner join Country CT
    on CT.country_id=C.country_id
 where M.message_type=0 
 and   datediff(curdate(),M.posted) >366 
 and   datediff(U.date_of_birth, str_to_date('1/01/1991', '%m/%d/%Y')) < 366
 and   CT.name='Australia'
```